# Sitecore 7 indexing PDF from file system

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

How can we index PDF files from filesystem in sitecore.
It's indexing only the files from Media Library -> Files, but i need to index all the files stored in a specific folder from file system.

The path looks like http://somedomain.com/PDF

Comment: what is the reason why don't you add files to sitecore?

Comment: Its the requirement, so that i can easily maintain all the files centrally in file system